# Select id from one query and use it in another

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code. In the first query I want it to select a pid. Then I want to somehow use the selected pid as WHERE in the second query. This do not work but I want it to work on this(the same) page. I have read about this on other forums but I still didn't fix it. Probably a small mistake somewhere.

```html
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo mysqli_connect_error();
}

$loggedInUserId = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$resu = mysql_query("SELECT pid FROM users WHERE id='$loggedInUserId';");
$ro = mysql_fetch_row($resu);

$sql= "SELECT pid, project_name, image, image_type FROM project WHERE pid ='". $row["pid"]. "';";

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    
        //$type= "Content-type:".$row['image_type'];
    //header ($type);
    echo "<form action='respodents.php' method='post'><button name='submit' id='projectbutton'>
            <div> 
                <img src=pic.php?pid=".$row['pid']." width=100px height=100px/>"." <div  id='project_name'>".$row['project_name']."</div>"."
       
            <input type='hidden' name='pid' value='".$row['pid']."'>
            <input type='hidden' name='project_name' value='".$row['project_name']."'>
            
            </div>
       </button></form>";
    }}

mysqli_close($mysqli);

?>
```

Comment: Very intresting question. I really hope you solve this!

Comment: you are mixing the mysql_* functions with the mysqli_* functions

Comment: Could you show us the error?

Comment: try debugging using `var_dump($ro);`  && then `var_dump($result);` and as BRoebie said do not mix mysql && mysqli

Comment: Wouldn't someone typically store the "loggedinuserid" in the session, so you can just do all that in 1 select query? And yes, don't mix mysqli <- note the i and mysql <- note no i.

Comment: Also - you are using both `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions.. and a mix of procedural and OO!

Comment: You can do this in one query as well. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37c09/3 Remember to swap out `users.id = 1` with a placeholder `users.id = ?` and bind `$loggedInUserId` as a param. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With respect to the sql, perhaps this might work

```
SELECT `pid`, `project_name`, `image`, `image_type` 
    FROM `project` WHERE `pid` = ( 
        SELECT `pid` FROM `users` WHERE `id`='$loggedInUserId'
    );
```

The original code had a mix of `mysql` and `mysqli` functions with a further mix of `Object Orientated` and `Procedural` method calls. Whilst this wouldn't cause an error necessarily it is bad practise to do so. Below is all in a procedural style - it's not tested but it incorporates the two queries into one which should work ( famous last words )

**Sidenote:** That said - with `mysqli` you can take advantage of `prepared statements` which help mitigate against the threat of sql injection - it's quite straightforward to lean and use - so rather than embedding a variable in the sql you would use a placeholder and then bind a variable to that.

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    /* db connection? */


    if( mysqli_connect_errno() ) echo mysqli_connect_error();
    else {

        $loggedInUserId = $_SESSION['user_id'];

        $sql="select `pid`, `project_name`, `image`, `image_type` 
            from `project` 
            where `pid` = ( 
                select `pid` from `users` where `id`='$loggedinuserid'
            );";

        $resu=mysqli_query( $mysqli, $sql );
        if( $resu ){

            $ro = mysqli_fetch_row( $resu );

            while( $row=mysqli_fetch_object( $resu ) ){

                echo "<form action='respodents.php' method='post'>
                        <button name='submit' id='projectbutton'><!-- you cannot re-use IDs, they MUST be unique! -->
                            <div> 
                                <img src'=pic.php?pid=".$row->pid."' width='100px' height='100px'/>
                                <div id='project_name'>".$row->project_name."</div><!-- you cannot re-use IDs, they MUST be unique! -->
                                <input type='hidden' name='pid' value='".$row->pid."'/>
                                <input type='hidden' name='project_name' value='".$row->project_name."'/>
                            </div>
                        </button>
                   </form>";

            }
        }
        mysqli_close( $mysqli );
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ro = mysql_fetch_row($resu);

$sql= "SELECT pid, project_name, image, image_type FROM project WHERE pid ='".      
$row["pid"]. "';";
```

`$ro = mysql_fetch_row($resu);` should be spelled `$row` not `$ro`. There's nothing in the variable you are calling in your SQL statement.

Also, your SQL Statement doesn't make much sense in terms of

```
$row["pid"],
```

you are accessing a numerical array with mysql_fetch_row(http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php).

If anything, you want to do mysql_fetch_array or mysql_fetch_assoc, to fetch an associative array that you can access the "pid" data statement. The way you are doing it with fetch_row you want to access it numerical, i.e.,

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,email FROM people WHERE id = '42'"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $row[0]; // 42
echo $row[1]; // the email value
```

The above is copied directly from the php mysql_fetch_row docs.

Edit::
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php
Mysqli Docs for fetch_row.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not be mixing mysql and mysqli. Let's use mysqli as mysql is deprecated.

I will assume that you don't need it to be in just one query since you never specified.

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT pid FROM users WHERE id='$loggedInUserId';");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
    $pid = $row['pid'];
}

$sql= "SELECT pid, project_name, image, image_type FROM project WHERE pid ='". $pid. "';";

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

Also, you really should learn to use prepared statements as they are a much safer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to change this code:

```
$resu = mysql_query("SELECT pid FROM users WHERE id='$loggedInUserId';");
```

to:

```
$resu = mysql_query("SELECT pid FROM users WHERE id='".$loggedInUserId."'");
```

And do not mix mysql and mysqli commands you can easly mess up you code that way.

Answer (score 0):

This looks smelly

```
$ro = mysql_fetch_row($resu);

$sql= "SELECT pid, project_name, image, image_type FROM project WHERE pid ='". $row["pid"]. "';";
```

change `$ro = mysql_fetch_row($resu);` to `$row = mysql_fetch_row($resu);`