# getting id filtered from a query and using it in another query

Tags: mysql, sql

I've queried user_invitations.inviter_id with filter I want which is:

```
select 
  inviter_id, 
  count(inviter_id) as invited_cnt
from user_invitations
group by 
  inviter_id
having 
  invited_cnt >= 52
order by 
  invited_cnt
```

From here I am trying to use only inviter_id to get id in another table called user (i.e. want to get user_id that match inviter_id I've just got above)

I've tried doing inner joing

```
from users
inner join (
    select inviter_id, count(inviter_id) as invited_cnt
    from user_invitations
    group by inviter_id
    having invited_cnt >= 52
    order by invited_cnt
)user_inv
on users.id = user_inv.id;
```

no luck, I thought about using subquery

```
from users
where id in (
    select inviter_id
    from user_invitations
    where inviter_id in (
        select count(inviter_id) as invited_cnt
        from user_invitations
        group by inviter_id
        having invited_cnt >= 52
    )
    group by inviter_id
);
```

but in most inner query it I cannot find out a way to return inviter_id after filtering by invited_cnt >= 52. How can I achieve this, is it not possible since to use having invited_cnt >= 52 we need aggreate count?

I've looked at some resources:
[Select id from one query and use it in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532083/select-id-from-one-query-and-use-it-in-another)

but none of them seem to deal with aggregate.

Comment: In short, you want `inviter_id` and `invited_cnt`, plus the `user_id` from another table that is equals to the `inviter_id`, or the `inviter_id` as a foreign key to `users` table?

Comment: Yes but I don't care whether or not I have invited_cnt, would be better if I had it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question, this query should give you the `user_id` from `user` that matched the `inviter_id`

```
SELECT
    us.inviter_id, 
    count(us.inviter_id) AS invited_cnt,
    u.user_id
FROM user_invitations AS us
JOIN user AS u ON u.user_id = us.inviter_id //just change the column name if needed
GROUP BY
  us.inviter_id
HAVING
  invited_cnt >= 52
ORDER BY 
  invited_cnt
```

If you are expecting only one `user_id`, then I think this should work. Although it would be nice if you included your table structure plus some sample data and expected output

Comment: I did not set it as a foreign key but user_id from user and inviter_id are the same

Comment: Check the edit. Though, if `user_id` and `inviter_id` are just the same, why bother getting `user_id` as stated in your question? If you want the other columns, then the query should work, just add the columns that you wish to be retrieved